# Flutter - get location with AndroidAlarmManager and Location

Tags: flutter, dart, location, android-alarms

I'm currently looking for a solution to send a device location every minute or so.

I'm trying to do it using the AndroidAlarmManager and Location libraries. Here is my code snippet :

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jardiparc/services/sync.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'jardiparc.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(Provider(create: (_) => SyncService(), lazy: false, child: JardiParc()));
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), 1, sendLocation, exact: true);
}

void sendLocation() async {
  print(DateTime.now().minute.toString() + ':' + DateTime.now().second.toString());
  print('send location');

  Location location = new Location();
  var currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
}
```

When I run this code, I keep getting this error :

```
E/flutter (14488): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLocation on channel lyokone/location)
E/flutter (14488): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (14488): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14488): #1      Location.getLocation (package:location/location.dart:135:10)
```

I have tried to do a `flutter clean` but it didn't work.

Any help on this one will be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

- Check that you have initialized the plugin correctly: [follow this link](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager/versions/0.4.5+20)
- Check that you have location permissions:

```
Location location = new Location();

bool _serviceEnabled;
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
LocationData _locationData;

_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    return;
  }
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}

_locationData = await location.getLocation();
```

- Change

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), 1, sendLocation, exact: true);
```

to

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), sendLocation, exact: true);
```

You have put a parameter **1** that should not be